# Azure Blob Storage changing Encryption Scope for existing container

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to change encryption scope for existing Azure Blob Storage container. I am using Azure Management API and related SDK. When I try to set encryption scope new container everything works fine:

```
var container = new BlobContainer(name:"testcontainer2", defaultEncryptionScope:"testscope", denyEncryptionScopeOverride: true);
var res = await client.BlobContainers.CreateWithHttpMessagesAsync("cmkpoc", "cmktest", "testcontainer2", container);
```

This successfully creates new container and I see custom encryption scope assigned in Azure Portal (container properties):

[image]

Unfortunately when I try to modify existing container I still get 200 response from Azure API but encryption scope is not changed. Code:

```
var container = new BlobContainer(name:"testcontainer", defaultEncryptionScope:"testscope", denyEncryptionScopeOverride: true);
var res = await client.BlobContainers.UpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync("cmkpoc", "cmktest", "testcontainer", container);
```

Container properties in this case:

[image]

This make me think that encryption scope may not be supported but I can't find that in Storage documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

•   When you create a container, it will automatically select an encryption scope, but you can’t change the encryption scope after the container is created since the encryption scope when created is already defined by the encryption parameters, i.e., Microsoft-managed default keys or Customer managed keys.

•   But there is a way you can select the customer managed key encryption scope at the time of creating a container or blob as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Encryption scope-container]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/encryption-scope-manage?tabs=portal#upload-a-blob-with-an-encryption-scope – Refer the ‘Upload blob with an encryption scope’ section for more details
•   Also, if you create a container without selecting the encryption scope, it configures the container with the default encryption scope as ‘$account-encryption-key’ as shown below.

[image: Default encryption scope]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/encryption-scope-overview#encryption-scopes-for-containers-and-blobs – Refer the ‘encryption scopes for containers and blobs’ section for more details.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am not trying to change name of container, I am using two containers. You are saying:

"you don't need to modify your code or applications to take advantage of Azure Storage encryption"

I need to use customer managed keys. For this reason I need to setup encryption scope on container when customer setup CMK.